# Display sweetAlert popup after page reload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopify, sweetalert

I have a form and when I submit the sweetAlert window appears but immediately disappears, as the page reloads and goes to the customer's account.
I'm looking for a way to display the sweetAlert after the page has reloaded.
Her is my button

```html
<button class="flex-c-m size27 btn effect02 s-text33 trans-0-4" onsubmit="confirm_login()"  type="submit">
         <i class="fas fa-unlock-alt p-r-5"></i> 
</button>
```

And my `script` code

```js
    function confirm_login() {
  if (document.getElementById('customer_email').value == 0 || document.getElementById('customer_password').value == 0) {
    toastr["error"]("Veuillez d'abord remplir tous les champs !");
  }
  else {
    swal({
      icon: 'success', 
      title: "Message!",
      text: "Message 2",
      type: "success",
      // timer: 3000
      }),
      function(){ 
          location.reload();
}
```

Somehow this code is not working.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Is this customer login form in Shopify?

Comment: Yes. The login form is Shopify fashe theme.

Comment: I think you need to add the code directly on the account page, show the poup.